# SharedPreferences shows null in Fragment (Android)

Tags: android

I am soo frustrated. In my very simple MainActivity I created a very simple Preference and everything works fine. I can display the value in other Activities, there are no errors or something.

```
preference = getSharedPreferences("testPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

val editor = preference.edit()
editor.putString("nameOfUser", "TEST")
editor.apply()
```

Now I created a SettingsFragment and I want to display in this Fragment the value of the SharedPreferences - and it doesn't work. I tried like the example above, but it shows me the value `null`. I don't understand it why is it soooo difficult, when I'm using a Fragment?

Fragment:

```
var preference: SharedPreferences? = context?.getSharedPreferences("testPreference", 0)

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_profilesettings, rootKey)
    println(preference?.getString("nameOfUser", "error"))
}
```

Comment: Please put the code of Fragment,

Comment: added, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
var preference: SharedPreferences? = context?.getSharedPreferences("testPreference", 0)
```

When the `Fragment` is created, there's no `Context` associated with it yet. So, you can't use `Context` in the preference declaration.

Try something like:

```
var lateinit preference: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    preference = context?.getSharedPreferences("testPreference", 0)
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_profilesettings, rootKey)
    println(preference?.getString("nameOfUser", "error"))
}
```

The same error does not happen with an `Activity` because an `Activity` is also a `Context`. `Fragment`s on the other hand aren't `Context`. It receives a `Context` sometime later after its creation via `onAttach(Context context)`

Answer (score 2):

You are using a different `Preferences` name inside your  `SettingsFragment` check

You need to Use **`testPreference`**  Instead of **`nameOfUser`**

> Use this

```
preference = getSharedPreferences("testPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

> Instead of

```
preference = getSharedPreferences("nameOfUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

**UPDATE**

```
lateinit preference: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
preference = context?.getSharedPreferences("testPreference", 0)
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_profilesettings, rootKey)
    println(preference?.getString("nameOfUser", "error"))
}
```

Comment: mistake from me, I copied the wrong line. just edited, sorry. I can promise you, the name are exactly the same in the code

Comment: @jamesxbrown you still have the same problem?

Comment: @NileshRathod `preference` needs `lateinit`. however, thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and @W0rmH0le was a little bit faster than you and has a declaration too. However, big thank you from me! :)